# Category of Enriched $\mathcal{V}$-categories is a monoidal model category?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, enriched-category-theory

Let $(\mathcal{V},\otimes_\mathcal{V},I_{\mathcal{V}})$ be a combinatorial closed symmetric
monoidal model category satisfying Schwede-Shipley’s monoid axiom, then it is possible define on the category of $\mathcal{V}$-enriched categories, we denote this category with $Cat(\mathcal{V})$, a combinatorial model structure called Dwyer-Kan model structure; this fact was proved by Fernando Muro in Theorem 1.1 of his article "DWYER–KAN HOMOTOPY THEORY OF ENRICHED CATEGORIES'' (https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1575).

Moreover, it is well known, that $Cat(\mathcal{V})$ is a closed monoidal category (I think it is also symmetrical but I have some doubts at this time) where the tensor product of two enriched categories $A,B$ is the enriched category $A\otimes B$ whose objects are products of objects of $B$ and $A$ and whose $\mathcal{V}$-homs are the tensors of $\mathcal{V}$-homs, i.e. for each pair of object $(x,y)$, $(a,b)$ of $A\otimes B$, $A\otimes B((x,y)(a,b))\cong A(x,a)\otimes_{\mathcal{V}} B(y,b) $; for a more detailed definition of the closed monoidal structure see section 7.3 of Categorical Homotopy Theory (https://emilyriehl.github.io/files/cathtpy.pdf).

My question is the following:
with the above tensor and model structure, is $Cat(\mathcal{V})$  a combinatorial monoidal model category?

Comment: I don't understand. The first bit says that $Cat(V)$ has a combinatorial model structure and your question is whether or not $Cat(V)$ has a combinatorial model structure

Comment: My question is :has $Cat(\mathcal{V})$ a combinatorial MONOIDAL model structure?